# Install dependencies from requirements.txt in Google Colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory

How to install python dependencies using a requirements file in Google Colab?

Like the equivalent of `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: What error do you get when you try that (with a leading !) in a notebook cell?

Comment: I am not sure what path to give for the requirements file

Comment: If you want to upload local files, you should check out [this example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb). If the file is hosted on the web, can you just pass the URL to pip?

Answer (score 23):

With Daniel's hint above, I was able to solve it.

Using the "uploading files from local computer script" I uploaded my requirements.txt file onto Google Colab platform. Script is found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=vz-jH8T_Uk2c&line=4&uniqifier=1). This is the script,

```
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
  print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(
      name=fn, length=len(uploaded[fn])))
```

The output on executing, clearly says that, it is saving this file as 'requirements.txt'. I couldn't however find this file in Google Drive, which is fine by me. Then,

```
!pip install -r requirements.txt
```

worked!

Answer (score 14):

You can write a file using the IPython magic function `%%writefile` then just do a `!pip install -r requirements.txt`

ie:

**Cell 1**

```
%%writefile requirements.txt

<contents of your requiements.txt>
```

**Cell 2**

```
!pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You Cannot find the Uploaded file in Google Drive. Because it is uploaded in the Python 3 Google Backend Compute Engine. When you Terminate the Session the all the files and data will be deleted.

Comment: Yes, we need to upload and install requirements every time the container / session is reset (not kernel)

Answer (score 0):

try;

```
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: The top answer covers `pip install -r requirements.txt` already. Is the `python -m` really necessary?

Answer (score -1):

U can use

```
pip install -r"path"
```

Comment: I think you should explain your answer and highlight why it differs from the others in the post.